# Why is this Awk file not producing any output?

Tags: unix, command-line, awk

The command:

```
awk –f cs2ss.awk < dataset.csv > dataset.ss
```

should be using this program:

```
BEGIN  {FS = ",";}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf("%s ", $i);}
  printf("\n");
}
```

To take all of the commas out of dataset.csv. But it only creates the empty file dataset.ss. I've made sure all files being used are .txt and not rtf (using a MacBook). What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: A screenshot of the input file -

[image]

Comment: Works for me .. by the way, you don't need the `<`. I.e., I used this line: `awk -f so.awk data.txt` since you asked about it

Comment: Works for me too. What does the .csv look like? Could it be some Unicode/linefeed problem?

Comment: What could I be doing wrong? I've tried looking at the output file in textedit and textwrangler. Could you list the steps you took? I know this sounds like a fairly simple thing but I can't seem to solve it!

Comment: You might want to create your own tiny .csv file and verify yourself that your code is working, then figure out what's different about your original, larger, data file.

Comment: Why are you using awk for this: `tr , ' ' < dataset.csv > dataset.ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works.  You can test it by simply running

```
awk –f cs2ss.awk
```

And typing in sample lines of input.  So you must be doing something else wrong and that thing is not apparent from here.

Things to try....

Run

```
awk –f cs2ss.awk < dataset.csv
```

If you get non-empty output to the screen, then there's something odd about the destination file or filesystem.  If you get blank output to screen, there's a problem with the input file.

If it's the input file, what does

```
file dataset.csv
```

tell you?

Comment: I added some possible diagnostic steps to my original answer.

Comment: The `<` isn't needed, and how is this an answer to OP's problem? .. fit for a comment.

Comment: @Levon, I think you must have commented just a split second before I added the diagnostic tips.  Almost makes me wish I hadn't modded up your comment :P  As for the <, it's not necessary for this utility but it's idiomatic cli syntax.  "cat dataset.csv | awk" would be objectionable, but not use of <.

Comment: Okay so blank output, so it must be the input file. When I do file communities.data (the input file in this instance) I get "ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators"

Comment: Hmm.  It *might* be those DOS line terminators.  Try changing the BEGIN line to 'BEGIN  {FS = ","; RS = "\r\n";}' and see what happens.  You might also have to try "\r?\n".

Comment: No, still nothing! Any other ideas? I'm desperate over here :(

Comment: How long are those very long lines?  "head -n 1 data.csv | wc -c" should tell you how many characters are in the first line and "head -n 1 data.csv | grep -o , | wc -l" would tell you how many commas (and therefore fields) there are.  Then modify your awk script so that it reports the value of NF.  If there's a discrepancy, we have some new information.

Comment: 618 characters... and 0 commas :S

EDIT: Sorry, made an error there. 127 commas

Comment: I put "printf("NF = ", NF);" at the end of the .awk and nothing is happening. Is this correct? I've never written awk before :(

Comment: FWIW: I just created a data file with 4 lines of 621 characters each (2484 total), including the CRLF line ending, on a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.7.5.  Using `/usr/bin/awk`, I get perfectly good output from my input data.  The only minor oddity is that the carriage return is followed by a space (because under Unix, CR is just another character) — the output was 2488 characters, the difference being those spaces.

Comment: I'm afraid I discovered the actual reason for my problem much later on. As I suspected, it was a stupid, silly mistake:

I was copying the "awk –f cs2ss.awk < dataset.csv > dataset.ss" command from the PDF handout. It turns out the dash/hyphen/whatever you-want-to-call-it was a different ascii character to the one my terminal was expecting me to simply type in. You can only imagine how ape-**** I went when my friend pointed this out. I appreciate everyone taking the time to help me on this anyway. Lesson learned - I must type commands myself.